# I Am Having Sewing Problems

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am following a tutorial and I am trying to make clothes for my character. The tutorial is saying to use sewing to make the clothes. It was kind of working but you could see gaps in the seams. Does anyone know how to fix this? Also, after it sews together is jiggles around and when it is being sewed, it goes through the mesh. If anyone can help me with this it would be much appreciated.
[image]

I tried to grow the geometry in order to stop it from going through the mesh and to give it more geometry for the seams to look better and I also changed the max sewing force to 5 in order to make it stop going through the mesh and that worked, but now it slides off the mesh. I tried to turn up the friction all the way to 1 in the collision but it still kept sliding off. Does anyone know how to fix that?

I then turned up the max sewing force to 20 to see if that would then stop the sliding, but when I did that, it still slid off. I kept turning it up and up but once I reached 50, it was still sliding off and it was also going through the mesh.

I actually tried it again and it was starting to go through the mesh at a max sewing force of 20. I then changed it to 17 and it stopped going through the mesh but still did slide off

[image]

I then continued with the tutorial and made the shirt. The high max sewing force made the shirt go through the mesh so I turned it down again. Now it has a weird jiggly movement again. It still slides off too.

[image]

I turned the max sewing force down to five in order to get rid of it going through the mesh and then I moved the shirt up but it still makes the jiggly motion and goes through the mesh.

[image]

At the end of the animation, the shirt finally comes to a rest, but the pants still slide down.

After adding a subdivision subsurface and a solidify modifier, I think I found out what the problem is but don't know how to fix it. It seems like the cloth, instead of sewing together, is pulsating. I tried to disable self collisions but it was still pulsating. Here is what it looks like with the subdivision subsurface and the solidify modifier.

[image]

If anyone can figure out how to stop the cloth from pulsating, that would be great. Other than that I think that the only other problem I have is how to keep the pants from falling off. Help is appreciated.

I managed to keep the pants on by scaling them smaller than the shirt, but it is still shaking. Does anyone know how to keep it from shaking?

[image]

Another interesting thing is, each time I make a change, it sews together just fine, but then once I play the animation a second time, it does the weird shaking thing.

Comment: A link to the tutorial might help.

Comment: Here it is:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPz5gk_AT6w&t=1103s